# I need to increase total supply of ERC20 token transferred to a 2/3 gnosis safe

Tags: tokens, gnosis-safe, mint

our team deployed an ERC20 token contract that supports supply increasing via a mint function.

We plan to move the token into a gnosis safe, and only allow the mint to happen with a 2-out-of-3 signature.

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this on gnosis front-end. What is the right way to do this with code?

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the contract directly through https://getlaika.app/